# What is the data type of image in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

What is the data type of image in PHP?

According to http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_datatypes.asp PHP supports the following data types:

- String
- Integer
- Float (floating point numbers - also called double)
- Boolean
- Array
- Object
- NULL
- Resource

So where does image fit in the above data types?

In my case the images are stored in database. In MySQL database they are stored in a table in a column whose data type is LONGBLOB. In SQL Server database they are stored in a table in a column whose data type is IMAGE.

Comment: It can vary. I can be a resource if you create/read it in using image functionality. It could be a string if it is base 64 encoded.

Comment: its a resource or string

Comment: If I may suggest a better source than w3schools.  I suggest using the official PHP manual: http://php.net/types

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to use [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

PHP strings do not necessarily have to contain plain text. For instance, the [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) function, which returns `string`, can read binary files just fine.

In [Details of the String Type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details) we can read this:

> The string in PHP is implemented as an array of bytes and an integer
>   indicating the length of the buffer. It has no information about how
>   those bytes translate to characters, leaving that task to the
>   programmer. There are no limitations on the values the string can be
>   composed of; in particular, bytes with value 0 (“NUL bytes”) are
>   allowed anywhere in the string (however, a few functions, said in this
>   manual not to be “binary safe”, may hand off the strings to libraries
>   that ignore data after a NUL byte.)
>
> This nature of the string type explains why there is no separate
>   “byte” type in PHP – strings take this role. Functions that return no
>   textual data – for instance, arbitrary data read from a network socket
>   – will still return strings.

Answer (score 0):

The image in the database is most likely a path to the image, therefore you would need to use strings.

A string can be virtually anything. In your example a string would be something like this:

```
c:\images\image_path\1.png
```

or

```
//www.domain.com/path/to/image.png
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_string.asp

Comment: The question mentions that images come from a database BLOB.